# Basic CRUD application for Product, Category & Location with SQLite

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, sqlite, crud

I improved the code from my previous [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/103821/productmanager-a-basic-crud-for-products-with-sqlite).

At this moment, the 3 entities have not yet a connection with each other. They should only be available for CRUD actions in a SQLite database.

I would like to have a review of this basic CRUD application so I can improve and learn from your experience. The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/Mithos-Yggdrasill/Datumcontrole/tree/43ddcb6d04afea5a5172853f0d2c3b419ff59ef8).

1. Design pattern/coding principles improvement that could be used
2. Testing
3. Exception handling
4. Readability
5. Coding best practices (code duplication, ...)
6. What should be Javadocumented?

**DatumControle.java**

```
public class DatumControle {

    private Repository db;

    public DatumControle(String dbType) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            db = RepositoryFactory.createDatabase(dbType);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            db.addProduct(product);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            System.out.println(product);
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Product getProductByEan(long ean) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            return db.getProductByEan(ean);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Product getProductByHope(int hope) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            return db.getProductByHope(hope);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Collection<Product> getAllProducts() throws ServiceException {
        try {
            return db.getAllProducts();
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void updateProduct(Product product) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            db.updateProduct(product);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void deleteProduct(long ean) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            db.deleteProduct(ean);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void addCategory(Category category) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            db.addCategory(category);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Category getCategory(String name) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            return db.getCategory(name);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Collection<Category> getAllCategories() throws ServiceException {
        try {
            return db.getAllCategories();
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void updateCategory(Category category) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            db.updateCategory(category);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void deleteCategory(String name) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            db.deleteCategory(name);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void addLocation(Location location) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            db.addLocation(location);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Location getLocation(String name) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            return db.getLocation(name);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Collection<Location> getAllLocations() throws ServiceException {
        try {
            return db.getAllLocations();
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void updateLocation(Location location) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            db.updateLocation(location);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void deleteLocation(String name) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            db.deleteLocation(name);
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            throw new ServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

**RepositoryFactory.java**

```
public class RepositoryFactory {

    public static Repository createDatabase(String dbType) throws DatabaseException {
        if(dbType.equals("sqlite")){
            return new SQLiteRepository("jdbc:sqlite:‪DatumControle.sqlite");
        }
        throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASETYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }

}
```

**Repository.java**

```
public interface Repository {

    public void addProduct(Product product) throws DatabaseException;

    public Product getProductByEan(long ean) throws DatabaseException;

    public Product getProductByHope(int hope) throws DatabaseException;

    public Collection<Product> getAllProducts() throws DatabaseException;

    public void updateProduct(Product product) throws DatabaseException;

    public void deleteProduct(long ean) throws DatabaseException;

    public void addCategory(Category category) throws DatabaseException;

    public Category getCategory(String name) throws DatabaseException;

    public Collection<Category> getAllCategories() throws DatabaseException;

    public void updateCategory(Category category) throws DatabaseException;

    public void deleteCategory(String name) throws DatabaseException;

    public void addLocation(Location location) throws DatabaseException;

    public Location getLocation(String name) throws DatabaseException;

    public Collection<Location> getAllLocations() throws DatabaseException;

    public void updateLocation(Location location) throws DatabaseException;

    public void deleteLocation(String name) throws DatabaseException;

}
```

**SQLiteRepository.java**

```
public class SQLiteRepository implements Repository {

    private SQLiteProductRepository productDb;

    private SQLiteCategoryRepository categoryDb;

    private SQLiteLocationRepository locationDb;

    public SQLiteRepository(String url) throws DatabaseException {
        productDb = new SQLiteProductRepository(url);
        categoryDb = new SQLiteCategoryRepository(url);
        locationDb = new SQLiteLocationRepository(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void addProduct(Product product) throws DatabaseException {
        productDb.addProduct(product);
    }

    @Override
    public Product getProductByEan(long ean) throws DatabaseException {
        return productDb.getProductByEan(ean);
    }

    @Override
    public Product getProductByHope(int hope) throws DatabaseException {
        return productDb.getProductByHope(hope);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Product> getAllProducts() throws DatabaseException {
        return productDb.getAllProducts();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateProduct(Product product) throws DatabaseException {
        productDb.updateProduct(product);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteProduct(long ean) throws DatabaseException {
        productDb.deleteProduct(ean);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCategory(Category category) throws DatabaseException {
        categoryDb.addCategory(category);
    }

    @Override
    public Category getCategory(String name) throws DatabaseException {
        return categoryDb.getCategory(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Category> getAllCategories() throws DatabaseException {
        return categoryDb.getAllCategories();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateCategory(Category category) throws DatabaseException {
        categoryDb.updateCategory(category);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCategory(String name) throws DatabaseException {
        categoryDb.deleteCategory(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void addLocation(Location location) throws DatabaseException {
        locationDb.addLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public Location getLocation(String name) throws DatabaseException {
        return locationDb.getLocation(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Location> getAllLocations() throws DatabaseException {
        return locationDb.getAllLocations();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateLocation(Location location) throws DatabaseException {
        locationDb.updateLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteLocation(String name) throws DatabaseException {
        locationDb.deleteLocation(name);
    }

}
```

**ProductRepository.java**

```
public interface ProductRepository {

    public int size() throws DatabaseException;

    public void addProduct(Product product) throws DatabaseException;

    public Product getProductByEan(long ean) throws DatabaseException;

    public Product getProductByHope(int hope) throws DatabaseException;

    public Collection<Product> getAllProducts() throws DatabaseException;

    public void updateProduct(Product product) throws DatabaseException;

    public void deleteProduct(long ean) throws DatabaseException;

}
```

**SQLiteProductRepository.java**

```
public class SQLiteProductRepository implements ProductRepository {

    private Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement statement;
    String url;

    public SQLiteProductRepository(String url) throws DatabaseException {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() throws DatabaseException {
        String query = "SELECT COUNT(ean) AS size FROM product";
        int size = 0;
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            ResultSet r = statement.executeQuery();
            r.next();
            size = r.getInt("size");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, ex);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public void addProduct(Product product) throws DatabaseException {
        if (product == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_NULL);
        }
        String query = "INSERT INTO product (ean, hope, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            statement.setLong(1, product.getEan());
            statement.setInt(2, product.getHope());
            statement.setString(3, product.getName());
            statement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ProductAlreadyExistsException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_ALREADY_EXISTS, e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Product getProductByEan(long ean) throws DatabaseException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE ean = ?";
        Product product = null;
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            statement.setLong(1, ean);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                product = new Product();
                product.setEan(result.getLong("ean"));
                product.setHope(result.getInt("hope"));
                product.setName(result.getString("name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
        if (product == null) {
            throw new ProductNotFoundException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND_EAN);
        }
        return product;
    }

    @Override
    public Product getProductByHope(int hope) throws DatabaseException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE hope = ?";
        Product product = null;
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            statement.setInt(1, hope);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                product = new Product();
                product.setEan(result.getLong("ean"));
                product.setHope(result.getInt("hope"));
                product.setName(result.getString("name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
        if (product == null) {
            throw new ProductNotFoundException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND_HOPE);
        }
        return product;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Product> getAllProducts() throws DatabaseException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM product";
        Collection<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setEan(result.getLong("ean"));
                product.setHope(result.getInt("hope"));
                product.setName(result.getString("name"));
                products.add(product);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
        return products;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateProduct(Product product) throws DatabaseException {
        if (product == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_NULL);
        }
        String query = "UPDATE product SET hope = ?, name = ? WHERE ean = ?";
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            statement.setInt(1, product.getHope());
            statement.setString(2, product.getName());
            statement.setLong(3, product.getEan());
            statement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteProduct(long ean) throws DatabaseException {
        String query = "DELETE FROM product WHERE ean = ?";
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            statement.setLong(1, ean);
            statement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    private void initiateStatement(String query) throws DatabaseException {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_NOT_FOUND, ex);
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection() throws DatabaseException {
        try {
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_CLOSSING_CONNECTION, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**SQLiteCategoryRepository.java**

```
public class SQLiteCategoryRepository implements CategoryRepository {

    private Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement statement;
    String url;

    public SQLiteCategoryRepository(String url) throws DatabaseException {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() throws DatabaseException {
        String query = "SELECT COUNT(name) AS size FROM category";
        int size = 0;
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            ResultSet r = statement.executeQuery();
            r.next();
            size = r.getInt("size");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, ex);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCategory(Category category) throws DatabaseException {
        if (category == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.CATEGORY_NULL);
        }
        String query = "INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES (?, ?)";
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            statement.setString(1, category.getName());
            statement.setString(2, category.getColor());
            statement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new CategoryAlreadyExistsException(ErrorMessages.CATEGORY_ALREADY_EXISTS, e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Category getCategory(String name) throws DatabaseException {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.NAME_NULL);
        }
        String query = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE name = ?";
        Category category = null;
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            statement.setString(1, name);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                category = new Category();
                category.setName(result.getString("name"));
                category.setColor(result.getString("color"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
        if (category == null) {
            throw new CategoryNotFoundException(ErrorMessages.CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return category;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Category> getAllCategories() throws DatabaseException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM category";
        Collection<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                Category category = new Category();
                category.setName(result.getString("name"));
                category.setColor(result.getString("color"));
                categories.add(category);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
        return categories;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateCategory(Category category) throws DatabaseException {
        if (category == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.CATEGORY_NULL);
        }
        String query = "UPDATE category SET color = ? WHERE name = ?";
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            statement.setString(1, category.getColor());
            statement.setString(2, category.getName());
            statement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCategory(String name) throws DatabaseException {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.NAME_NULL);
        }
        String query = "DELETE FROM category WHERE name = ?";
        initiateStatement(query);
        try {
            statement.setString(1, name);
            statement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    private void initiateStatement(String query) throws DatabaseException {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_NOT_FOUND, ex);
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection() throws DatabaseException {
        try {
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_CLOSSING_CONNECTION, e);
        }
    }

}
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {

    public static final int EAN_MIN_LENGTH = 8;

    public static final int EAN_MAX_LENGTH = 13;

    public static final int HOPE_MIN_LENGTH = 4;

    public static final int HOPE_MAX_LENGTH = 8;

    public static final int NAME_MIN_LENGTH = 2;

    public static final int NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 30;

    private long ean;

    private int hope;

    private String name;

    public Product() {
    }

    public long getEan() {
        return ean;
    }

    public void setEan(long ean) {
        if (ean < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_EAN_NEGATIVE);
        }
        if (InputValidator.isLengthLessThan(ean, EAN_MIN_LENGTH)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_EAN_MIN_LENGTH);
        }
        if (InputValidator.isLengthGreaterThan(ean, EAN_MAX_LENGTH)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_EAN_MAX_LENGTH);
        }
        this.ean = ean;
    }

    public int getHope() {
        return hope;
    }

    public void setHope(int hope) {
        if (hope < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_HOPE_NEGATIVE);
        }
        if (InputValidator.isLengthLessThan(hope, HOPE_MIN_LENGTH)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_HOPE_MIN_LENGTH);
        }
        if (InputValidator.isLengthGreaterThan(hope, HOPE_MAX_LENGTH)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_HOPE_MAX_LENGTH);
        }
        this.hope = hope;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.NAME_NULL);
        }
        name = name.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
        name = name.replaceAll("\r|\n", "");
        name = name.toLowerCase().trim();
        if (!name.matches("^[.,a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.NAME_NOT_ALPHANUMERIC);
        }
        if (InputValidator.isLengthGreaterThan(name, NAME_MAX_LENGTH)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
        }
        if (InputValidator.isLengthLessThan(name, NAME_MIN_LENGTH)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_NAME_MIN_LENGTH);
        }
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 83 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.ean);
        hash = 83 * hash + this.hope;
        hash = 83 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Product)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Product other = (Product) obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.ean, other.ean)
                && this.hope == other.hope
                && Objects.equals(this.name, other.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ean + "\t" + hope + "\t" + name;
    }

}
```

**ProductTest.java**

```
public class ProductTest {

    private Product chips;

    public ProductTest() {
    }

    long pow(long a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (b == 1) {
            return a;
        }
        if (isEven(b)) {
            return pow(a * a, b / 2); //even a=(a^2)^b/2
        } else {
            return a * pow(a * a, b / 2); //odd  a=a*(a^2)^b/2
        }
    }

    boolean isEven(double num) {
        return ((num % 2) == 0);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        chips = new Product();
        chips.setEan(8710398016591L);
        chips.setHope(23968);
        chips.setName("250GR LAY S BICKY CRISP");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        chips = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void setEan_Param_is_new_ean() {
        long newEan = pow(10L, Product.EAN_MIN_LENGTH - 1);
        chips.setEan(newEan);
        assertEquals(newEan, chips.getEan());
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void setEan_IllegalArgumentException_If_param_has_less_than_MIN_digits() {
        long newEan = pow(10L, Product.EAN_MIN_LENGTH - 2);
        chips.setEan(newEan);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void setEan_IllegalArgumentException_If_param_has_more_than_MAX_digits() {
        long newEan = pow(10L, Product.EAN_MAX_LENGTH);
        chips.setEan(newEan);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void setEan_IllegalArgumentException_If_param_is_negative() {
        long newEan = pow(-10L, Product.EAN_MIN_LENGTH - 1);
        chips.setEan(newEan);
    }

    @Test
    public void setHope_Param_is_new_hope() {
        int newHope = (int) Math.pow(10, Product.HOPE_MIN_LENGTH - 1);
        chips.setHope(newHope);
        assertEquals(newHope, chips.getHope());
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void setHope_IllegalArgumentException_If_param_has_less_than_MIN_digits() {
        int newHope = (int) Math.pow(10, Product.HOPE_MIN_LENGTH - 2);
        chips.setHope(newHope);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void setHope_IllegalArgumentException_If_param_has_more_than_MAX_digits() {
        int newHope = (int) Math.pow(10, Product.HOPE_MAX_LENGTH);
        chips.setHope(newHope);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void setHope_IllegalArgumentException_If_param_is_negative() {
        int newHope = (int) Math.pow(-10, Product.HOPE_MIN_LENGTH - 1);
        chips.setHope(newHope);
    }

    @Test
    public void setName_Param_is_converted_without_linebreak_and_set_to_name() {
        String newName = "\nnieuwe\n productnaam1\n\r\n";
        chips.setName(newName);
        assertEquals("nieuwe productnaam1", chips.getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void setName_Param_is_trimmed_and_set_to_name() {
        String newName = "   nieuwe productnaam1    ";
        chips.setName(newName);
        assertEquals("nieuwe productnaam1", chips.getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void setName_Param_is_converted_to_lowercase_and_set_to_name() {
        String newName = "NiEUwe PrODUcTnaAm1";
        chips.setName(newName);
        assertEquals("nieuwe productnaam1", chips.getName());
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void setName_IllegalArgumentException_If_param_is_null() {
        String newName = null;
        chips.setName(newName);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void setName_IllegalArgumentException_If_param_does_not_only_consists_of_alphanumeric_char() {
        String newName = "<?php echo lol; ?php>nieuwe productnaam1";
        chips.setName(newName);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void setName_IllegalArgumentException_If_param_If_param_has_less_than_MIN_characters() {
        String newName = new String(new char[Product.NAME_MIN_LENGTH - 1]).replace("\0", "a");
        chips.setName(newName);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void setName_IllegalArgumentException_If_param_If_param_has_more_than_MAX_characters() {
        String newName = new String(new char[Product.NAME_MAX_LENGTH + 1]).replace("\0", "a");
        chips.setName(newName);
    }

}
```

**Category.java**

```
public class Category {

    public static final int NAME_MIN_LENGTH = 2;

    public static final int NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 20;

    private String name;

    private String color;

    public Category() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.NAME_NULL);
        }
        name = name.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
        name = name.replaceAll("\r|\n", "");
        name = name.toLowerCase().trim();
        if (!name.matches("^[.,a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.NAME_NOT_ALPHANUMERIC);
        }
        if (InputValidator.isLengthLessThan(name, NAME_MIN_LENGTH)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.CATEGORY_NAME_MIN_LENGTH);
        }
        if (InputValidator.isLengthGreaterThan(name, NAME_MAX_LENGTH)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.CATEGORY_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
        }
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        if (color == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.COLOR_NULL);
        }
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(color);
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ErrorMessages.COLOR_NOT_HEXADECIMAL);
        }
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 23 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        hash = 23 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.color);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Category other = (Category) obj;
        return (Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) 
                && (Objects.equals(this.color, other.color));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

**InputValidator.java**

```
public class InputValidator {

    public static boolean isLengthGreaterThan(Object obj, int maxLength) {
        return String.valueOf(obj).length() > maxLength;
    }

    public static boolean isLengthLessThan(Object obj, int minLength) {
        return String.valueOf(obj).length() < minLength;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Use try-with-resources

Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) when working with resources like database connections, statements, file handlers.

#### Odd throw-away objects

This kind of code is quite strange:

> ```
> ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
> while (result.next()) {
>     product = new Product();
>     product.setEan(result.getLong("ean"));
>     product.setHope(result.getInt("hope"));
>     product.setName(result.getString("name"));
> }
> ```

That is,
if there are multiple results,
this will overwrite `product` in each iteration with a different product.
Effectively, the value of `product` will be the last match.

I think you want to replace the `while` with an `if`.

#### Too much boilerplate, repeated

This pattern is repeated several times:

> ```
> @Override
> public Product getProductByEan(long ean) throws DatabaseException {
>     String query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE ean = ?";
>     Product product = null;
>     initiateStatement(query);
>     try {
>         statement.setLong(1, ean);
>         ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
>         while (result.next()) {
>             product = new Product();
>             product.setEan(result.getLong("ean"));
>             product.setHope(result.getInt("hope"));
>             product.setName(result.getString("name"));
>         }
>     } catch (SQLException e) {
>         throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY, e);
>     } finally {
>         closeConnection();
>     }
>     if (product == null) {
>         throw new ProductNotFoundException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND_EAN);
>     }
>     return product;
> }
> ```

A couple of things wrong with it:

- Depends on objects manipulated outside, such as `connection`, `statement`
- Depends on specific sequence of manipulations that the compiler cannot enforce: call `initiateStatement` first, do the job, call `closeConnection` at the end
- Tedious repetition of the try-catch in each such method

It would be better to rewrite this in a way that `connection` and `statement` are not be member fields, not shared by multiple methods.
You could achieve that, and reduce boilerplate code,
by introducing a query runner interface:

```
interface QueryRunner<T> {
    T query(PreparedStatement statement) throws SQLException;
}
```

Next, add a utility method that takes a `QueryRunner` instance,
and encapsulates the details of managing a connection:

```
private <T> T query(String query, QueryRunner<T> runner, String message) throws DatabaseException {
    try (
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ) {
        try {
            return runner.query(statement);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(message, e);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DatabaseException(ErrorMessages.DATABASE_NOT_FOUND, e);
    }
}

private <T> T queryForObject(String query, QueryRunner<T> runner, String message) throws DatabaseException {
    return query(query, runner, message);
}
```

Armed with these,
writing the `getProductByEan` method,
and the other similar methods can be simplified,
with less boilerplate code:

```
public Product getProductByEan(long ean) throws DatabaseException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE ean = ?";
    Product product = queryForObject(query, new QueryRunner<Product>() {
        @Override
        public Product query(PreparedStatement statement) throws SQLException {
            statement.setLong(1, ean);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setEan(result.getLong("ean"));
                product.setHope(result.getInt("hope"));
                product.setName(result.getString("name"));
                return product;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }, ErrorMessages.DATABASE_FAULT_IN_QUERY);
    if (product == null) {
        throw new ProductNotFoundException(ErrorMessages.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND_EAN);
    }
    return product;
}
```

Using this approach,
`connection` and `statement` are no longer member variables,
their scopes are minimized, which is much safer.

For add/delete/update methods that don't return an object,
you can create another helper method:

```
private void update(String sql, QueryRunner<Void> runner, String message) throws DatabaseException {
    query(sql, runner, message);
}
```

And in the implementation of the anonymous `QueryRunner<Void>` class,
you can `return null`.

#### Make members `final` when you can

The `url` variable in the repository classes can be final.
In fact, they should be `private static final String URL`.